# Meteor iron router with angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, iron-router

I've got a very simple web application using Meteor and Angular. I'm trying to use iron router for server api routes and angular ui router for client side. I've set up my code to allow iron-router to place the `ui-view` into all routes and then have angular ui-router take over from there.

The problem is a race condition. No matter what I do, where I place my source files, iron-router will ALWAYS execute it's block after ui-router. I've followed many answers from SO about this but for some reason my implementation isn't working. Below is the code for my app.

Routes file:

```
Router.route('/(.*)', function(){
  console.log('iron router');
  this.render('app');
});

angular.module('my_app').config(
  function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

  console.log('ui router');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'client/views/home.ng.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('test', {
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'client/views/test.ng.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl'
  })

  ;

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

The meteor template:

```
<template name="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
</template>
```

The `console.log` output is always:

`ui router
iron router`

What am I missing?!?!?!????

Comment: What Meteor package for Angular do you use? Or if you get Angular into browser only, from CDN of Bower, why won't you use it in form of [a Meteor package](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/bootstrapping)?

Comment: I'm using urigo:angular

Comment: @SumanLama I did find a solution. I ended up downloading the package source from GitHub and modifying the source to my needs to bundle into a custom package stored within my project.

Comment: @traviswingo would you share your custom solution as gist?